# Game Maker Studio Not Drawing Variable?

Tags: game-maker

```
///Draws
draw_set_color(c_red);
draw_text(view_xview + 128, view_yview + 128, string(global.fuel));
```

Why isn't it drawing my variable?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, always use view's index:

```
draw_text(view_xview[0] + 128, view_yview[0] + 128, string(global.fuel));
```

Next, what you need check:

1. Current alpha (`draw_set_alha(1);` before draw)
2. Current blend mode (`draw_set_blend_mode(bm_normal)`)
3. Depth of the object. Maybe you drew behind other objects. Draw order is from biggest value to lower value. If two objects has same depth (and they overlaps) you need set different depth.
4. Used font includes needed chars (and you set it using`draw_set_font(...)`)
5. Used correct alignment (`draw_set_halign(...)` and `draw_set_valign(...)`)
6. Object exists. Maybe you didn't create it. Or maybe you deactivated it. Or maybe you deleted it.